# Outlook VBA, how to only delete emails older than 90 days

Tags: vba, outlook

I have got a piece of code that deletes all emails within a specific folder but I am needing it to only delete the emails that are older than 90 days and was hoping someone would be able to help me, I have listed the code down below;

```
Sub RemoveAllItemsAndFoldersInDeletedItems()
    Dim oDeletedItems As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolders As Outlook.Folders
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim i As Long
    'Obtain a reference to deleted items folder
    Set oDeletedItems = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
    Set oItems = oDeletedItems.Items
    For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
        oItems.Item(i).Delete
    Next
    Set oFolders = oDeletedItems.Folders
    For i = oFolders.Count To 1 Step -1
        oFolders.Item(i).Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can just set up an inbox rule to do that.

Comment: Yes, but I've been asked to set up a button with a macro behind it to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an If statement to compare the current date with the sent date of each email in the loop.

Change the oItems For loop as follows:

```
For i = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    If DateDiff("d", oItems.Item(i).SentOn, Now) > 90 Then
        oItems.Item(i).Delete
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it running perfect.