# Is it possible to find related emails and loop the results in the background?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'd like to find related emails to the email I have currently selected. Then I want to loop the results.

Using the `ActiveExplorer.Search` takes a moment, and at the same time the code keeps running. So it doesn't return any results, because of loading still happening in the background, I guess.

So my questions are:

- How do I find related emails?
- How do I loop the search results (in the background)?

To find related emails, maybe something like this:

```
Sub FindRelatedEmails()
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set ns = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    
    Dim strFrom As String
    strFrom = oMail.SenderName
    
    Dim strSubject As String
    strSubject = oMail.ConversationTopic
    
    Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
    Set myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
     
    Dim txtSearch As String
    txtSearch = "[Konversation]:=""" & strSubject & """"
    
    myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.Search txtSearch, olSearchScopeAllFolders
    
    ' Problem occurs below, since the code keeps running but the search results haven't loaded yet.
    myOlApp.ActiveExplorer.SelectAllItems
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count To 1 Step -1
        Dim Item As MailItem
        Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i)
        Debug.Print Item.Subject, Item.Sender, Item.Parent.FolderPath
    Next
    
    Set ns = Nothing
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set myOlApp = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.search - "The Search method does not provide a callback to enable the developer to determine when the search is complete." You could try a delay function such as the one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66798650/auto-save-attachment-from-outlook-365

Comment: Or Work with Conversation.GetRootItems - Example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196066/4539709

Comment: @0m3r your link provides a better way to do this. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Application.AdvancedSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch) instead - it exposes [Application.AdvancedSearchComplete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearchcomplete) event.

Answer (score 0):

The [Explorer.Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.search) method is used to perform a Microsoft Instant Search on the current folder displayed in the Explorer using the given Query. Basically, it will use Outlook UI for searching items and the result is visible in Outlook. The functionality of `Explorer.Search` is analogous to the Search button in Instant Search. It behaves as if the user has typed the query string in the Instant Search user interface and then clicked Search. When calling `Search`, the query is run in the user interface, and there is no programmatic mechanism to obtain the search results. The `Search` method does not provide a callback to enable the developer to determine when the search is complete.

Instead, you may find the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class helpful. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also you may consider using the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the `Application` class helpful. The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

The Outlook Object Model provides the `AdvanvedSearchComplete` event of the `Application` class. An instance of the `Search` class containing the search results is passed to the event handler (see the `Results` property).

See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.